# Caffe build fail: Makefile:591: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/util/io.o' failed

Tags: machine-learning, caffe, build-error

Hello I' ve got issue on caffe installation. I did everything in accordance to the instruction https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-Installation-Guide (for CPU version)
On command make all I've got the following output:

```
CXX src/caffe/util/io.cpp
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:52:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:48,
                 from src/caffe/util/io.cpp:6:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h:421:4: error: #error "OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support"
 #  error "OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support"
    ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/array:35:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h:426,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:52,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:48,
                 from src/caffe/util/io.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support \
  ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:58:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:48,
                 from src/caffe/util/io.cpp:6:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:389:12: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&&’ token
     Ptr(Ptr&& o);
            ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:389:16: error: invalid constructor; you probably meant ‘cv::Ptr<T> (const cv::Ptr<T>&)’
     Ptr(Ptr&& o);
                ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:390:25: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&&’ token
     Ptr& operator = (Ptr&& o);
                         ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:1033:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:58,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:48,
                 from src/caffe/util/io.cpp:6:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/ptr.inl.hpp:256:16: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&&’ token
 Ptr<T>::Ptr(Ptr&& o) : owner(o.owner), stored(o.stored)
                ^
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/ptr.inl.hpp:256:1: error: prototype for ‘cv::Ptr<T>::Ptr(cv::Ptr<T>)’ does not match any in class ‘cv::Ptr<T>’
 Ptr<T>::Ptr(Ptr&& o) : owner(o.owner), stored(o.stored)
 ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:58:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54,
                 from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:48,
                 from src/caffe/util/io.cpp:6:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:319:5: error: candidates are: template<class T> template<class Y> cv::Ptr<T>::Ptr(const cv::Ptr<Y>&, T*)
     Ptr(const Ptr<Y>& o, T* p);
```

Here is also a lot of text in output but I cannot upload it because of limit on number of characters

```
Makefile:591: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/util/io.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/util/io.o] Error 1
```

Can somebody help me with this problem?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 
cmake version 3.5.1
Cuda version: 10.0.130

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in 4th version of OpenCV. Caffe dosen't work with it. When I installed 3rd version everything was ok.